# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass when iterating over hash in chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am not exactly a chef expert and I very likely could be overlooking something silly.  I am trying to iterate over a hash in a chef recipe (chef client 12.5.1) and am receiving **undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass**

I am at a loss as to why, but perhaps I have been staring at it too long.  Any help is appreciated.

### Attributes

```
default['haproxy']['default']['frontends']['main'] =
  { socket: '*:5000', default_backend: 'default-backend' }

default['haproxy']['default']['frontends']['http'] =
  { socket: '*:80', default_backend: 'default-backend' }

default['haproxy']['test']['frontends']['main'] =
  { socket: '*:6000', default_backend: 'test-backend' }

default['haproxy']['test']['frontends']['https'] =
  { socket: '*:443', default_backend: 'test-backend' }

default['haproxy-shared']['default-backend']['servers'] = [
  { name: 'app1', socket: '127.0.0.1:5001', options: ['check'] },
  { name: 'app2', socket: '127.0.0.1:5002', options: ['check'] },
  { name: 'app3', socket: '127.0.0.1:5003', options: ['check'] },
  { name: 'app4', socket: '127.0.0.1:5004', options: ['check'] }
]

default['haproxy']['shared']['default-backend']['options'] = [
  'balance roundrobin',
  'option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost'
]

default['haproxy-shared']['test-backend']['servers'] = [
  { name: 'app1', socket: '127.0.0.1:5001', options: ['check'] }
]
```

### Recipe Error

Note: I added in the pp for troubleshooting purposes.

```
   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

   Cookbook Trace:
   ---------------
     /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/ga_haproxy_default/recipes/default.rb:12:in `block in from_file'
     /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/ga_haproxy_default/recipes/default.rb:8:in `each'
     /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/ga_haproxy_default/recipes/default.rb:8:in `from_file'

   Relevant File Content:
   ----------------------
   /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/ga_haproxy_default/recipes/default.rb:

     5:  # Copyright (c) 2016 Sean McGowan, All Rights Reserved.
     6:  require 'pp'
     7:
     8:  node['haproxy'].each do |instance_name, inst|
     9:    ga_haproxy instance_name
    10:
    11:  pp inst['frontends']
    12>>   inst['frontends'].each do |fe_name, frontend|
    13:      ga_haproxy_frontend fe_name do
    14:        instance_name instance_name
    15:        socket frontend['socket']
    16:        default_backend frontend['default_backend']
    17:        action :enable
    18:      end
    19:    end
    20:
    21:    node['haproxy-shared'].each do |be_name, backend|
```

The pretty print shows the contents of the variable during the ruby pass.

```
   Synchronizing Cookbooks:
     - ga_haproxy (0.1.1)
     - ga_haproxy_default (0.1.0)
   Compiling Cookbooks...
   {"main"=>{"socket"=>"*:5000", "default_backend"=>"default-backend"},
    "http"=>{"socket"=>"*:80", "default_backend"=>"default-backend"}}
   {"main"=>{"socket"=>"*:6000", "default_backend"=>"test-backend"},
    "https"=>{"socket"=>"*:443", "default_backend"=>"test-backend"}}
```

*inst* was originally *instance* but I changed it to see if it was clashing with something by chance; however, the contents are iterable in irb.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Edit:  I also ran it against chef client 12.14.89 and recieved the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `default['haproxy']['shared']` line probably, that has no `frontends` key. Did you mean to change that one to `haproxy-shared` too? Print out the `instance_name` to be sure. Remember that `nil.to_s == ''` so you might not see the logging you expect.

Comment: **Doh!**  Too long in front of the screen yesterday I guess.  Thanks for the extra pair of eyes @coderanger!